# Visual Studio Code javascript suggestions is not working properly, too many annoying options

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual studio code has too many annoying suggestions.

[image: annoying suggestions]

But the real one are not showing at the first time, unless we input enough prefix characters.

Any idea? Wrong settings?